# My fullscreen menu won't work. What did I do wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigationbar

So this is the code for my current site I'm working on but I'm unsure of where I messed up! Please help! I'm new to coding as well so please don't be /too/ harsh. I've been checking this and trying to refine everything and clean it up as best as I can for people to look at so they can try to help. I didn't catch anything while doing so either. I'm very very new to jQuery so I'm thinking it has something to do with the linking of the jQuery to the file or however that works but I have absolutely no idea.

```
    PROBLEM RESOLVED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get all the cdn libraries from this link.
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Put this library inside your head tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and add your script inside the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     /// put your script code here
 });
```

like this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".menu-toggle").on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass("on");
              $('.menu-section').toggleClass("on");
              $("nav ul").toggleClass('hidden');
        });
     });
```

Comment: Thank you and thank you to everyone else. I am finally educated on how to put jQuery into my webpages. I went through too much struggle but hey we all start somewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should place your `click` event within your `$(document).ready(function(){ //click event goes here });`. Take a look at this fiddle, because I believe everything is working as you intended.

This is assuming you are linking to the proper JS files.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k3eLevt2/)

**EDIT**

If your jQuery files are in the root of your folders then simply link to them using...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.11.3.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
```

Of course you would replace the first jQuery file with the actual version you are using. Place these in the footer of your website.

Comment: I may need help linking. That seems to be my issue... I have 2.1.4 downloaded and in my root folder. I also have my script.js in the same root folder.

Sorry for my stupidity

Comment: Okay so I am linking my jQuery library to Google now. I've found the code for that and that is what I am inserting into my code right above </head> Do I just insert me script under that with the script tag? I've been trying so much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import jQuery and put your own Javascript after you've done the import.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Always best to put your Javascript at the bottom of your html page, before the `</body>`

Comment: What does your string of code mean? I'm new to jQuery.